# Some MySQL slave errors?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

- Master version: mysql-server-5.5.14-1.el5.remi
- Slave version: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.24-23.6.340
- Binlog format: ROW based

I'm using [PRM](https://github.com/jayjanssen/Percona-Pacemaker-Resource-Agents/blob/master/doc/PRM-setup-guide.rst) to setup HA for MySQL.

Sometime, MySQL slave stopped with some errors:

```
Error executing row event: 'Table 'reportingdb.tvc_ads_tag_date' doesn't exist'
```

`[Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Update_rows event on table reportingdb.7k_banner_channel_tmp; Can't find record in '7k_banner_channel_tmp', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.000854, end_log_pos 859094925, Error_code: 1032`

`120828  0:36:13 [Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Write_rows event on table reportingdb.7k_bookings_ver; Duplicate entry '1518' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log mysql-bin.001022, end_log_pos 509479, Error_code: 1062`

`Error 'Error in list of partitions to DROP' on query. Default database: 'reportingdb'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE v3_ban_date_cpm7k DROP PARTITION pcurrent_201298'`

and the `mysql.sock` is missing but the MySQL processes still exist. Pacemaker cannot restart due to the below errors:

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

I have to login via TCP (`-h 127.0.0.1`) and stop MySQL first, then let `corosync` start MySQL again.

In summary, the question is:

1. How do I solve the above slave errors and prevent them from happening in the
   future?
2. Why is the `mysql.sock` missing?  How do I make the Pacemaker better handle this situation?

Answer (score 11):

It's better not to skip by hundreds. Just loop one-by-one:

```bash
until mysql -e "show slave status\G;" | grep -i "Slave_SQL_Running: Yes";do
  mysql -e "stop slave; SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; start slave;";
  sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: It now actually solves the reason, but it's nice automatization for problem fixing.

Answer (score 4):

just stop the slave using

```
mysql> stop slave;
```

Then set the global variable `sql_slave_skip_counter` to `1`, for example:

```
mysql> set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1;
```

Then start the slave:

```
mysql> start slave;
```

Then check if the slave is working or not:

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
```

If the error is still there, set a bigger value in `sql_slave_skip_counter` like:

```
mysql> set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1000;
```

Again, check the status of the slave.

If you find the `skip_sql` value is non zero in the slave status then stop the slave again and do:

```
mysql> set global sql_slave_skip_counter=0;
mysql> start slave;
```

Comment: skip slave counter is not something to take lightly. It is ONLY OK to use it when familiar with the context of the statement that failed replication and accepting that skipping it is an acceptable data drift on the slave. But as a general answer this is a way to break integrity of the slave as a true replica of the master

Comment: I have to echo TechieGurl here --- intermixed with the 1000 that you skip might be some good rows.   SKIP COUNTER skips *all* replication, not just the error ones.

Comment: Dose `set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1000;` means ignore 1000 records or more? If i do so how much of my data is missed on my slave replication?