# In replication A->B->C, can A be binlog_format=STATEMENT and B be binlog_format=ROW?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, master-slave-replication

I have replication setup between an on-prem MySQL 5.6 server (A) to another on-prem MySQL 5.6 server (B).  I was setting up an AWS DMS instance (C) that I wanted to migrate and then replicate.  It told me that I had, then, to have my binlog_format set to ROW-based replication.

Is this feasible?  Can I expect changes on A to replicate correctly to C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STATEMENT` → `ROW` is **absolutely** a valid configuration.

The thing you've probably overlooked is that Server B needs `log_slave_updates` enabled, or it won't replicate anything from A to C.

---

But to address the question at hand, consider the following table, which describes the comparison between configured `@@binlog_format` and what is actually written to the server's binlog.  Assume A is master, B is slave of A,  no changes are made directly to B, and of course `log_slave_updates` is enabled on B:

```
A binlog_format | A actually writes | B binlog_format | B actually writes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
STATEMENT         STATEMENT           STATEMENT         STATEMENT
STATEMENT         STATEMENT           MIXED             MIXED
STATEMENT         STATEMENT           ROW               ROW

MIXED             MIXED               STATEMENT         TOTALLY FAILS EVENTUALLY
MIXED             MIXED               MIXED             MIXED
MIXED             MIXED               ROW               ROW

ROW               ROW                 STATEMENT         TOTALLY FAILS VERY QUICKLY
ROW               ROW                 MIXED             ROW
ROW               ROW                 ROW               ROW
```

What's going on here?

When B writes to its binary log, it writes an entry to *replicate* the change it made.  It writes these entries in the format its local optimizer determines should be used.  When `STATEMENT` or `ROW` mode is in effect, that's the only choice, so incoming `STATEMENT` becomes outgoing `ROW`, in your case.  Server B easily translates because it executes the incoming event and then simply logs which rows it inserted/updated/deleted in its local data, and the values of the columns in those rows.

> Each MySQL Server can set its own and only its own binary logging format (true whether `binlog_format` is set with global or session scope). This means that changing the logging format on a replication master does not cause a slave to change its logging format to match. [...]
>
> Changing the binary logging format on the master while replication is ongoing, or without also changing it on the slave can cause replication to fail with errors such as Error executing row event: `'Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since statement is in row format and BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT.'`
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html

That's what I was referring to, above, with `TOTALLY FAILS`.  The only *invalid* configuration is for a server to be in `STATEMENT` mode while at least one upstream master is in `ROW` or `MIXED`.

Why?  Every possible query that can be represented in `STATEMENT` format can *always* be subsequently represented in `ROW` format, because `ROW` format is absolutely deterministic.  Conversely, no query replicated in `ROW` format can *ever* be subsequently replicated in `STATEMENT` format.

Note that `MIXED` format simply gives the local optimizer the option on a query by query basis of how to replicate -- `STATEMENT` or `ROW` -- but if the incoming replication event is `ROW` the only outgoing choice is also `ROW`.

---

Also, `STATEMENT` mode is seriously terrible.  Get away from it as soon as you can.  Before then, it's vitally critical to verify that the data on B is identical to the data on A in every way, because the data on B can slip out of sync much easier and go undetected when A is in `STATEMENT` mode.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation.  I forgot to mention that I have  log_slave_updates enabled; that was the first thing I tried.  Still this explanation clearly explains that my configuration should be valid, and why.

Comment: And now, I went to the trouble to validate this by standing up a new Server C on prem and it's working fine, A->B->C.  So this is likely an issue with the AWS DMS tooling, and not with MySQL replication.

Comment: What's DMS doing? Complaining? Or acting like everything is fine, except just "not working" (in what sense?)

Comment: The symptoms were that there were no errors, but a value change on A wasn't propagated through to C.  Just like `log_slave_updates` would have shown.  It's actually working now, though.  I didn't make any config changes but after validating a different "server C" worked just fine, I went back and found the Aurora instance connected through DMS is now suddenly working, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I am not comfortable with different [binlog_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) settings between Master and Slave (See my old post from 1.5 years ago [MySQL v5.1.73 - can the binlog_format betweem Master & slave be different?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104727/mysql-v5-1-73-can-the-binlog-format-betweem-master-slave-be-different/104802#104802))

In your particular case, I would make the Slave `STATEMENT` or the Master `ROW`. You could probably get away with `MIXED` on the Slave. If the Slave is `ROW` or `MIXED`, just be prepared for bigger logs.

I did mention in [my earlier post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104727/mysql-v5-1-73-can-the-binlog-format-betweem-master-slave-be-different/104802#104802) that you would have to experiment.

Here is what I believe would work

- `MIXED` Slave could replicate from `ROW` Master or `STATEMENT` Master
- `ROW` Slave could replicate from `ROW` Master or `MIXED` Master
- `STATEMENT` Slave could replicate from `STATEMENT` Master only

You should test this on Staging Servers and see.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations.  In my case, though, changing the binlog_format is outside the question; Server A (the prod master) I didn't want to touch while it's live, and Server C (The DMS migration instance) requires that Server B be set to ROW.  It isn't working though and I wanted to know if this configuration is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes they can and replication A->B->C will work correctly. Pros and cons of `ROW` and `STATEMENT` will apply respectively.

I can't justify using `STATEMENT` though.

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear, but I haven't been able to find any documentation explaining why it should work.  I have my own wild theories, of course.

Comment: I look at this setup as two master/slave couples: A->B and B->C. A slave can replicate from a master regardless the binlog format. Thus, I see no reason why it shouldn't work (again, besides usual stuff like non-deterministic queries and the `STATEMENT` format).
If you experience opposite please share your findings. It would be interesting to know.