# MySQL multi-master group replication on kubernetes

Tags: mysql-8.0, multi-master, group-replication, containers

We are trying to setup MySQL multi-master group replication (GR) on kubernetes [Group replication configuring instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-configuring-instances.html).
GR is starting on one pod after all the configurations. However the second node goes to RECOVERING state when GR is started followed by ERROR state.
There is no error in GCS_DEBUG_TRACE logs also.

Let me know if there is anything missing and if more info is required to analyze. Thanks in advance.

Workarounds tried:

1. [MySQL Group Replication Multi-Primary Setup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268801/mysql-group-replication-multi-primary-setup)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794695/mysql-group-replication-stuck-on-recovering-forever

Cluster Setup:

1. Created 3 PVCs for each pods in a namespace
2. Launched pods using mysql:8.0.23 docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)
3. Ran below queries to configure the pods

```
$ kubectl get all -n myb5
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mysql1   1/1     Running   0          15h
pod/mysql2   1/1     Running   0          15h
pod/mysql3   1/1     Running   0          15h

NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/gr-domain   ClusterIP   None         <none>        <none>    15h

$ kubectl get pvc -n myb5
NAME               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mysql-pv-claim-1   Bound    pvc-f7957eff-b75e-4dbc-990a-8d79e54b6f06   250Gi      RWO            robin          15h
mysql-pv-claim-2   Bound    pvc-1c5d4dfd-8495-4266-af0d-882ce8e8ccec   250Gi      RWO            robin          15h
mysql-pv-claim-3   Bound    pvc-49c0979b-49cb-413b-b695-479b32124343   250Gi      RWO            robin          15h
```

Configuration on all pods:

```
SET PERSIST general_log     = ON;
SET PERSIST general_log_file= '/var/lib/mysql/mysql1.log';
SET PERSIST group_replication_communication_debug_options='GCS_DEBUG_ALL';

SET PERSIST enforce_gtid_consistency=ON;
SET PERSIST gtid_mode       = OFF_PERMISSIVE;
SET PERSIST gtid_mode       = ON_PERMISSIVE;
SET PERSIST gtid_mode       = ON;

SET PERSIST binlog_format   = ROW;
SET PERSIST master_info_repository='TABLE';
SET PERSIST relay_log_info_repository='TABLE';
SET PERSIST transaction_write_set_extraction=XXHASH64;

SET SQL_LOG_BIN             = 0;
CREATE USER rpl_user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO rpl_user@'%';
GRANT BACKUP_ADMIN ON *.* TO rpl_user@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO SOURCE_USER='rpl_user', SOURCE_PASSWORD='password' FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery';
SET SQL_LOG_BIN             = 1;

INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';

SET PERSIST group_replication_group_name='85cbd4a0-7338-46f1-b15e-28c1a26f465e';
SET PERSIST group_replication_start_on_boot=OFF;
SET PERSIST group_replication_bootstrap_group=OFF;
SET PERSIST group_replication_single_primary_mode=OFF;
SET PERSIST group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks=ON;
SET PERSIST group_replication_member_expel_timeout=3600;
SET PERSIST group_replication_group_seeds='mysql1.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local:33061,mysql2.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local:33061,mysql3.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local:33061';
SET PERSIST group_replication_ip_allowlist='mysql1.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local,mysql2.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local,mysql3.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local';
```

Conf on pod1:

```
SET PERSIST server_id=1;
SET PERSIST group_replication_local_address= 'mysql1.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local:33061';
SET PERSIST group_replication_bootstrap_group=ON;
START GROUP_REPLICATION USER='rpl_user', PASSWORD='password';
SET PERSIST group_replication_bootstrap_group=OFF;
SET PERSIST group_replication_recovery_get_public_key=ON;
```

Conf on pod2:

```
SET PERSIST server_id=2;
SET PERSIST group_replication_local_address= 'mysql2.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local:33061';
START GROUP_REPLICATION USER='rpl_user', PASSWORD='password';
```

Conf on pod3:

```
SET PERSIST server_id=3;
SET PERSIST group_replication_local_address= 'mysql3.gr-domain.myb5.svc.cluster.local:33061';
START GROUP_REPLICATION USER='rpl_user', PASSWORD='password';
```

Group Replication Status when started:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  CHANNEL_NAME: group_replication_applier
     MEMBER_ID: 57b9f42a-8b4d-11eb-bd3e-0242ac110003
   MEMBER_HOST: mysql1
   MEMBER_PORT: 3306
  MEMBER_STATE: ONLINE
   MEMBER_ROLE: PRIMARY
MEMBER_VERSION: 8.0.23
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  CHANNEL_NAME: group_replication_applier
     MEMBER_ID: 57ec4b94-8b4d-11eb-8fdc-0242ac110004
   MEMBER_HOST: mysql2
   MEMBER_PORT: 3306
  MEMBER_STATE: RECOVERING
   MEMBER_ROLE: PRIMARY
MEMBER_VERSION: 8.0.23
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  CHANNEL_NAME: group_replication_applier
     MEMBER_ID: 57ec4b94-8b4d-11eb-8fdc-0242ac110005
   MEMBER_HOST: mysql3
   MEMBER_PORT: 3306
  MEMBER_STATE: RECOVERING
   MEMBER_ROLE: PRIMARY
MEMBER_VERSION: 8.0.23
```

Group Replication Error after few minutes:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  CHANNEL_NAME: group_replication_applier
     MEMBER_ID: 57ec4b94-8b4d-11eb-8fdc-0242ac110004
   MEMBER_HOST: mysql2
   MEMBER_PORT: 3306
  MEMBER_STATE: ERROR
   MEMBER_ROLE:
MEMBER_VERSION: 8.0.23
```